# Storing CURL requests when the receiving server is down

Tags: php, curl

I have a contact form, which sends non-sensitive data (name, message, a few checkboxes and address fields) to an external CRM system through a CURL request.

The problem is, sometimes the receiving system is down for maintenance, and I have to store the incoming requests somewhere temporary. Right now, I'm doing this manually when I receive a message for incoming maintenance, but this is not an option in the long run.

My question is, what's the best way to do automated storing and sending depending on the server status. I know it should depend on the CURL response code, and if it returns code 200, the script should check for any temporary stored requests to be sent alongside the current one, but I'm not sure exactly what's the best way to implement this - for example, I wonder if serialized request inside a database table is better than making a JSON array and storing it inside a file which is later deleted.

How would you solve this? Any kind of advice and tips you can give me is welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would perform the following procedure to make sure the HTTP request is being successfully sent to the target server:

1. Make sure that the server is up and running, you may want to use [**get_headrs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) to perform this check.
2. Depending on server's response from the previous step you will perform one of tow actions:

   1) If server response was OK then go a head and fire your request.

   2) If server response was NOT OK then you may want to to store the HTTP request in some serialized form in database.
3. Run a cronjob that reads all requests from DB and fire them, upon server's response, if the request went successfully then delete its record from DB table.

At the ocasion of cronjob running, i would use [**HttpRequestPool**](http://php.net/manual/en/httprequestpool.construct.php) to run all requests in parallel.

I would suggest using the DB storage instead of JSON file storage cause it will be easer to maintain specially in the case of having some of the HTTP requests being successfully processed by the server and some are not, in that case you want to remove the succesful ones and keep the others, this is much easer using a database.